# laravel 5.3 пути к изображениям после переноса на хостинг

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте, прошу Вашей помощи, сделал сайт на laravel 5.3, до этого не имел опыта с laravel, разрабатывал его на локальном сервере и устанавливал все через composer,  после переноса на shared хостинг возникли некоторые проблемы, которые удалось решить самостоятельно но не могу исправить эту, в общем  из таблицы товаров  выводится информация правильно, но путь к изображению не работает и открыть его по этой ссылке не выходит, есть подозрения что это все из-за композера. изображения лежат по адресу \storage\app\public\products\January2017 , но на локальном все работало минуя папки \app\public\, пробовал в ручную дописать адрес но не помогает, права на папки 777, что делать?

Comment: доступ на сервере есть только к папкам public, вам либо писать метод который будет выгребать картинки из\storage\app\public\products\January2017 или  кинуть линк в public можно и выбирать все нужно при помощи метода asset

Comment: вот по поводу кинуть линк в public , можете подсказать как это сделать? а то я не совсем понимаю

Comment: ln -s /path_to_folder /path_from_folder_link

Comment: я прошу прощения за глупость, но куда прописывать(

Comment: в консоле через ssh зайдите

Comment: вот с этим проблемка, сайт на shared хостинге и там нет ssh) есть ли еще какой-то способ?

Comment: А блин, не обратил внимание :( э ну тогда перенести изначально хранение все в public папку в настойках компонента который фотки сжимает

Comment: симлинк можно попробовать создать через exec

Comment: не подскажете как решили проблему?